# how to create a table in SQLAlchemy using Postgres?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4

Hi I'm trying to create a Table using SQLAlchemy in Postgres, it process all well but the table is not created in my Postgres server.

My models.py file:

```
 import sqlalchemy
 from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
 from sqlalchemy import Table
 from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

 Base = declarative_base()

 class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myTable'
    time_id = Column(String(), primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(String())
    inventory_id = Column(String())

    def toJSON(self):   
        json = {
           "time_id":self.alert_id,
           "customer_id":self.customer_id,
           "inventory_id":self.inventory_id,
       }
       return json
```

My creator file:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from models import MyTable
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

path="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/test"
engine = create_engine(path, echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Base` class is different for both file, you need to use the `Base` class which used for inheritance, so import your `Base` from models file:

```
#creatorfile
...
from models import Base

path="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/test"
engine = create_engine(path, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Remove this line `Base = declarative_base()`